# Relative position of two lines with a variable

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have two lines:

$ r_l:\begin{cases}lx-y=1 \\ x+ly-z=1 \end {cases}\ $

and

$s_l:\begin{cases}x+y=0 \\ y-lz=-1 \end {cases}\ $

and $l $ is a variable. As $ l $ varies, I have to find their relative position.

I'm guessing that you need to change them to parametric form, equate the equations and do some algebra manipulation, but the last point is where I'm having difficulties.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "relative position"?  Whether they are skew, parallel, or intersect?  And if they intersect, the angle between them?

You can always use one of the variables themselves as a parameter.

For the first line, from lx- y= 1 we get y= lx- 1.  Then x+ ly- z= 1 gives z= x+ ly+ 1= x+ l^2x- l+ 1= (1+ l^2)x.  Letting x= t we have the parametric equations x= t, y= lt- 1, z= (1+ l^2)t.  A tangent vector to the line is given by <1, l, 1+ l^2>.

For the second line, from x+ y= 0 we get y= -x.  Then from y- lz= -1, lz= y+ 1= -x+ 1 so z= -x/l+ 1/l.  Letting s= x/l (because I don't like fractions) x= ls, y= -ls, z= -s+ 1/l.  A tangent vector to the line is given by .

In order for the two lines to be parallel (or the same line) those tangent vectors would have to be in the same direction- one must be a multiple of the other so we must have 1= al, l= -al, and 1+ l^2= -a for some number a.  From l= -al, a= -1.  Then 1= al= -l so l= -1.  1+ l^2= 1+ 1= 2 which is NOT equal to -a= 1.  So the two lines are not the same line nor are they parallel.  The lines either cross or are skew.

To determine whether they cross we need to try to solve the equations x= t= ls, y= lt- 1= -ls, and z= (1+ l^2)t= -s+ 1/l for s and t.  Since t= ls, lt- 1= l^2s- 2= -ls so (l^2+l)s= 2, s= 2/(l^2+ 1) and t= ls= 2l/(l^2+ 1).  Then the third equation, for z, becomes (1+ l^2)t= (1+ l^2)[2l/(l^2+ 1)= 2l= -s+ 1/l= -2/(l^2+ 1)+ 1/l= (-2l+ l^2+ 1)/(l(l^2+ 1))= (l- 1)^2/(l^3+ l) which is definitely NOT 2l!

The lines do NOT intersect so must be skew lines.

Comment: While I understand what you did and I'm extremely grateful for your explanation, I just want to point out a small oversight when you say "since l =-al, a=-1" (you can do that only if you assume that l is not equal to 0). Also there may be some other minor mistakes, but you've been extremely helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you’re simply trying to find out whether or not the lines are skew, parallel, intersect or coincide, we can investigate this by examining the combined system of equations. The corresponding augmented matrix is $$A = \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}l&-1&0&1\\1&l&-1&1\\1&1&0&0\\0&1&-l&-1\end{array}\right].$$ For this system to have any solution at all, $A$ must be rank-deficient: $\det(A) = -l(2l+1)$, so the lines are definitely skew when $l\ne0$ and $l\ne-\frac12$. When $l=0$, we can see by inspection that both $A$ and the left-hand submatrix have rank 3, so the lines intersect at a single point. It’s not as obvious what’s going on when $l=-\frac12$, but row-reducing $A$ shows that there’s a single intersection point in that case, too.